# Jquery mobile cache issues with video tag

Tags: jquery-mobile, caching, html5-video, browser-cache

I have created a mobile web site using Jquery Mobile and applying the multipage template.
I have an issue while going to a page which displays a video thanks to the html5 video tag.
This video can be changed by another one with the exact same filename whenever an administrator decices to record a new sample.

Basically, I have this JQM page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="video-recorded" style="height: 100%">
<div data-role="content" style="height: 100%">  
    <div id="centre" class='centrage other'>
        <p>Recorded video</p>
        <div style="padding-top:10px;">
            <video id="recorded" width='640'  height='360' controls>
                <source id="recorded-mp4" src="http://172.17.0.50/recorded_videos/recorded.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source id="recorded-webm" src="http://172.17.0.50/recorded_videos/recorded.webm" type="video/webm">                    
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

that I access thanks to this piece of code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#video-recorded", {    
   transition: "none",
   reverse: false,
   changeHash: true
});
```

Just before showing the page, I update the link so that the browser tries to load the very last video record:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow",'#video-recorded',function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $("#recorded-mp4").attr("src","http://172.17.0.50/recorded_videos/recorded.mp4?t="+d.getTime());
    $("#recorded-webm").attr("src","http://172.17.0.50/recorded_videos/recorded.webm?t="+d.getTime());
});
```

But this cheat does not work and I'm very lost about what to do. I test this website on Safari (Ipad) and Firefox (Android) and none of them loads the newest video.
On Safari, I need to refresh the page to have the latest video whereas Firefox always displays the cached video.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by two steps:

1) Forget the multipage template and separate the pages in different html files.

```
$.mobile.changePage("./video-recorded.html", {  
    transition: "none",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: true,
});
```

This solved the problem on Safari / Android's default browser but not on Firefox

2) For mobile Firefox:
I added some PHP code to replace the  tag whenever the page is loaded. Consequently, I have something like this:

```
<video width='640'  height='360' controls autoplay>         
<?php
$int_rand = rand();
echo "
    <source src='./recorded_videos/recorded.mp4?t=".$int_rand."' type='video/mp4'>
    <source src='./recorded_videos/recorded.webm?t=".$int_rand."' type='video/webm'>
    <source src='./recorded_videos/recorded.ogv?t=".$int_rand."' type='video/ogg'>
";
?>
</video>
```